# "To hear someone's side," without "of the story": correct? Understandable? Not too informal?

Tags: phrases

It seems like "to hear someone's side of the story" is significantly more common than "to hear someone's side" without "of the story."

In the context of an essay, is the latter correct? Understandable? Not too familiar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase  "to hear someone's side" is common and would be understood by a fluent speaker, and would not be thought odd. Another common variation would be "To hear X's side of it."  In that form "it" is a place holder for "of the story" or "of the case" or some similar expression. Such an expression is implied by "I want to hear Joe's side before I make up my mind."

These shortened forms are perfectly correct and natural. Whether to use them or not is just a matter of style. Whether it is too informal depends on the context, but in spoken use or written dialog it would be proper except perhaps in an ultra-formal setting.